# Уточнение или нет: питьевой, этиловый и ядовитый, метиловый

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как здесь быть с запятыми? Видимо, должно быть одинаково: *питьевом, этиловом* и *ядовитом, метиловом*?

Многочисленные отравления заставили в военных снаряжениях все спиртовые жидкости производить на питьевом, этиловом спирте, а не на ядовитом метиловом.

Answer (score 1):

**Многочисленные отравления заставили в военных снаряжениях все спиртовые жидкости производить на питьевом, этиловом спирте, а не на ядовитом метиловом.**

1) Здесь прилагательные питьевой и этиловый приравнены к однородным (хотя по смыслу второе прилагательное поясняет первое), ставится запятая

2) Ядовитый – постоянное качество метилового спирта, поэтому ядовитый метиловый – неоднородные прилагательные, нет запятой.

3) **По смыслу  противопоставлены** прилагательные "этиловый и метиловый", а не питьевой и ядовитый.

4) **Одинаковое оформление** возможно в следующем случае: все спиртовые жидкости производить на **этиловом**, питьевом, а не на **метиловом**, ядовитом спирте. Здесь свойства спиртов представлены  в качестве дополнительной информации на втором месте.

Сравнить: **при перестановке**: все спиртовые жидкости производить на **питьевом**, этиловом, а не **на ядовитом**, метиловом спирте.   Разумеется, никто не собирается выбирать ядовитый спирт, поэтому такое противопоставление неверно.

Answer (score 0):

Либо две, либо ни одной. Конечно, должно быть одинаково. Я бы нигде не ставил. Уточнение или нет – зависит от автора.

Comment: Так уж «ни одной»?

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю, что должно быть одинаково... но вот автор сначала уточняет, а потом - нет, и поди разберись...

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете уточняющие члены предложения с пояснительными. В отличие от уточняющих членов предложения (которые сужают обозначаемое ими понятия), пояснительные члены предложения называют обозначаемые ими понятия по-другому.

Питьевой спирт - это бытовое название этилового спирта. Этиловый спирт - это научное название.

Пояснительные члены предложения выделяются запятыми.

> Корректно: Многочисленные отравления заставили в военных снаряжениях все спиртовые жидкости производить на питьевом **,** этиловом спирте **,** а не на ядовитом метиловом.

Answer (score 0):

Не весь этиловый спирт является медицинским, поскольку он бывает и техническим.([Химзаказ](http://himzakaz.net/novosti/24-meditsinskij-pishchevoj-i-tekhnicheskij-spirt-v-chjom-raznitsa)). Поэтому можно писать "питьевой этиловый" без запятой (питьевой этиловый в отличие от технического этилового). И тогда можно сказать:

**...на питьевом этиловом спирте, а не на ядовитом метиловом**

Но возможен и другой подход: питьевой противопоставлен ядовитому, а этиловый и 
метиловый - уточнения. Получается:

**...на питьевом, этиловом спирте, а не на ядовитом, метиловом**

Третий подход: питьевой и этиловый в повседневной жизни употребляются как синонимы. Тогда этиловый - пояснение. А противопоставляется этиловый спирт метиловому:

**...на питьевом, этиловом спирте, а не на ядовитом метиловом**